# how to get the SQL statement based on the process ID?

Tags: mysql, processlist

I run the SQL below ,after  that  I run  the  SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist to get the  SQL  statement  " update new_table set c1=c1+12", however the column info is null ,
so how to  get  the  statement ?

```
use   test_db;
start transaction;
update new_table set c1=c1+12
```

[image]

Comment: You need to commit the transaction

Answer (score 0):

If the Command column says "Sleep" then there's no SQL query running in that session. The client may have run the UPDATE query you showed, but that query has finished. It's only shown in the processlist while it's executing.

You can examine `performance_schema.events_statements_history_long` table to see previous queries that ran in each session. It takes a bit of work to join that table to the processlist. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/performance-schema-statement-tables.html